# Python PDFMiner reads "identical" PDF files differently

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfminer

Scenario:

1. A multitude of PDF files are created automatically by TCPOS. Each PDF refers to some type of summary, which is indicated by the title of the first page of every PDF file.
2. Since the creation of PDFs is automated, the structure of PDF files is assumed to be identical.
3. For organizing purposes, a Python script sorts the PDF files into folders depending on the content of the PDF file. The first step of the process is reading the title of each PDF file (code inspiration taken from [here](https://pdfminersix.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/composable.html)):

   ```py
   with open(file, 'rb') as pdf_file:
       output_string = StringIO()
       doc = PDFDocument(PDFParser(pdf_file))
       rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
       device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, output_string, laparams=LAParams())
       interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)

       for page in PDFPage.create_pages(doc):
           interpreter.process_page(page)
           break

   pdf_text_form = output_string.getvalue()
   pdf_title = pdf_text_form.split()[0]
   ```
4. The snippet above basically takes the first word of a PDF file in text form. The code works/has worked before for every single PDF file thrown at it *except one*.
5. A sample of `pdf_text_form` from any working PDF file looks something like this:

   ```
   Title_of_some_summary

   Location_of_facility
   1 Full visibility

   Shops:
   Registers:
   Waiter:
   Visibility:

   Registers
   Register
   Shop

   ...
   ```
6. A sample of `pdf_text_form` from the one exception PDF file looks something like this:

   ```
   Location_of_facility
   1 Full visibility

   Title_of_some_summary

   Shops:
   Registers:
   Waiter:
   Visibility:

   Registers
   Register
   Shop

   ...
   ```
7. Visually, the exception file looks identical to the working files. In every single working file `pdf_title` is correctly set to the title of the summary, except for the exception file where it takes the text from the 2nd line, which would be the location of the facility. (2nd line visually, first line according to `PDFPageInterpreter()`)
8. Obviously, assumption number one is that the PDF has been formatted differently, potentially a problem by TCPOS, as such I [converted both files to XML](https://products.aspose.app/pdf/conversion/pdf-to-xml) and compare the XML output. The first and the only difference besides actual content is the varying font `FamilyName` prefix (`TPLTAU` vs `VRASAU`) in both files:

   ```xml
   <Glyphs OutlineWidth="0.5" CharSpace="0" RenderTransform="1 0 -0 1 35.7165 62.340027">
       <Font SizePoints="36" Style="Regular" FamilyName="TPLTAU+Calibri,Bold" Capitals="Normal" ResourceId="1" />
       <Origin X="0" Y="0" />
       <Text>Title_of_some_summary</Text>
       <Size Width="265.81628" Height="36" />
       <Brush>
           <SolidBrush Color="#FFEA0000" />
       </Brush>
       <Tag>convertedFont</Tag>
   </Glyphs>
   ```
9. Every single line before that point is exactly identical. Every single following line is exactly identical besides the actual `<Text>` content and the 6 letter jumbled `FamilyName` prefix.

---

What is exactly happening here? This definitely feels like a bug in the PDFMiner library, but I'm not excluding a bug in TCPOS or human error either.

Comment: The differing font prefixes are used to denote subset fonts. Is every working file TPLTAU? Can you check the broken file carefully and make sure it has no non-ASCII characters in it?

Comment: I intentionally wrote *jumbled prefix* because I noticed it always being different. Here are three different working files with prefixes `PTRWVI`, `TPLTAU`, `BWOJKA` respectively. The broken file and even the title itself has non-ASCII-128 (ASCII-256 like äöü) characters just like the most of the working files.

Comment: If you run `cpdf -output-json -output-json-parse-content-streams in.pdf -o out.pdf` this should yield a file which you can search with a text editor to see the order of the text on each page. This might help you to work out at what stage of your pipeline the problem occurs, and what piece of software might be at fault.